# Partition a vector into chunks of equal sizes

Tags: r

I am trying to use `R` to partition a vector into equal groups.

An example is as follows. Suppose we have a vector `x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`, I want it to return all possible partitions of groups with 2 elements. One such example of a partition is {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}.

Is there a way to do this in `R`? Some functions like `expand.grid` seems related but does not work for the purpose in this example.

The ideal output that I would like to have is a `data.frame` as follows. For each row, I can take the first 2 elements as the members of the first group, the next 2 elements as the members of the second group, and the last 2 elements as the members of the last group. The following is just two examples of all possible partitions. I'd like to have a `data.frame` that contains all possible partitions.

```r
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    2    3    4    5    6    1
.....
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try with `combn` `combn(x, 2, simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks, @akrun! But this function returns all possible of 2-elements from `x`. I want to have a partition of the vector. For `combn(1:4, 2, simplify = FALSE)`, it returns the list `[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 3

[[3]]
[1] 1 4

[[4]]
[1] 2 3

[[5]]
[1] 2 4

[[6]]
[1] 3 4`. But what I want to have is something like (1 2, 3 4), (1 3, 2 4), (1 4, 2 3)

Comment: Just updated the question to state the structure needed more clearly. Ideally, a `data.frame` like that would work best in `R` I think. I wrote it as a tuple here in the comment because there is no way to write a `data.frame` in comment. But thanks for pointing out the confusion.

Comment: The simplify = FALSE is to return a list or else it returns a matrix

Comment: I think "partitions" is the word you're looking for - you want all possible partitions where each partition has a given size?

Comment: But `combn(x, 2, simplify = TRUE)` returns a matrix of all combinations of 2-elements, not all possible ways of partitioning the vector `x` into groups of 2-elements.

Comment: It is not clear to me precisely what you want but if you are looking for partitions there is a package of that name.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
all_chunks_size2 = function(x) {
   sapply(seq_len(length(x)), \(i) x[c(i, (i %% n+1))])
}

all_chunks_size2(x)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
# [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    1
```

Comment: Kind of, but is there a way to generate all possible partitions under this method?

Comment: Do you mean partitions of length 3, 4, etc.? Then yes that's possible but you'll have to modify `c(i, (i %% n+1))` to be more flexible

Answer (score 1):

```
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
result <- t(head(matrix(x[outer(seq_along(x) - 1, seq_along(x) - 1, `+`) %% length(x) + 1],nrow = length(x)),6))
result
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    2    3    4    5    6    1
[3,]    3    4    5    6    1    2
[4,]    4    5    6    1    2    3
[5,]    5    6    1    2    3    4
[6,]    6    1    2    3    4    5
```

Comment: Thanks, but looks like this is not all possible partitions? For example, rows 1, 3, 5 are actually identical because they consists of groups of (1, 2), (3, 4) and (5, 6)

Comment: Okay could you pls edit your question and specify the complete output required for your example?

Comment: I don't think it's possible if you want the output as a dataframe for the above example.

`(1    2    3    4    5    6), (2    3    4    5    6    1),(1    3    2    4    6    1) (or) (1    3    2    4    6    5)`

So anyhow in the 3rd row, the set is going to repeat.

Answer (score 1):

The `partitions` package will help here. `setparts(c(2, 2, 2))` gives a matrix where each column is a partition and each row is an element of the original set, and the values indicate which partition the element is in:

```
library(partitions)
p = setparts(c(2, 2, 2))
p
# [1,] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# [2,] 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
# [3,] 3 3 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 3 3 2 3 3 2
# [4,] 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 1 1 1 3 2 3
# [5,] 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 1 1 1
# [6,] 1 1 1 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 3
```

We can `order` the original set by each of these columns to generate the partitions. Here each partition is a pair of rows, the first partition is rows 1 and 2, the second rows 3 and 4, the third rows 5 and 6.

```
set = 1:6
apply(p, 2, \(x) set[order(x)])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1
# [2,]    6    6    6    2    2    2    3    3    3     4     4     4     5     5     5
# [3,]    2    2    2    3    3    3    2    2    2     2     2     2     2     2     2
# [4,]    5    4    3    6    5    4    6    4    5     6     5     3     6     4     3
# [5,]    3    3    4    4    4    5    4    5    4     3     3     5     3     3     4
# [6,]    4    5    5    5    6    6    5    6    6     5     6     6     4     6     6
```